# Java - Android app skipping 400+ frames

Tags: java, android, frames

When I run my app, it takes a very long time to load up. When it starts it is pretty laggy. When I am running my code I am getting this message in my logcat:

```
06-28 03:36:22.969: I/Choreographer(1506): Skipped 453 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I am thinking there is some kind of code in my main file that is slowing this whole thing down because it didn't do this for the longest time.  Also the fact that its skipping 453 frames means somethings not right.

Here is my code, its about 1000 lines so If anyone wants to read through it that would be awesome but if not if I could get lead into the direction of fixing this problem that would be great.

```
public class PlayScreen extends View {

// Constructor
public PlayScreen(Context context) {
    super(context);

    /**
     * Instantiate all variables.
     */

    playerBounds = new RectF();
    rowBlock = new RectF();
    rowBlock2 = new RectF();
    startPlaying = new RectF();
    continuePlaying = new RectF();
    rowGlow = new RectF();
    rowGlow2 = new RectF();
    menuBox = new RectF();
    continueplayingBounds = new RectF();

    meteorBounds = new RectF();
    pointLossBounds = new RectF();
    pointGainBounds = new RectF();
    speedBounds = new RectF();

    titleBounds = new RectF();
    playBounds = new RectF();

    doublePointsBounds = new RectF();
    bulletBounds = new RectF();
    ghostWallBounds = new RectF();
    wideGapsBounds = new RectF();


    ///// Colors /////

    colorGreen = new Paint();
    colorBlack = new Paint();
    colorWhite = new Paint();
    colorBlue = new Paint();
    colorYellow = new Paint();
    colorRed = new Paint();
    colorCyan = new Paint();
    colorMagenta = new Paint();
    colorOrange = new Paint();


    glowGreen = new Paint();
    glowWhite = new Paint();
    glowBlue = new Paint();
    glowYellow = new Paint();
    glowRed = new Paint();
    glowCyan = new Paint();
    glowMagenta = new Paint();
    glowOrange = new Paint();
    glowBlack = new Paint();

    translucentGrey = new Paint();

    transparent = new Paint();
    boostPaint = new Paint();
    countPaint = new Paint();

    align = null;

    // Set my basic color's
    colorGreen.setColor(Color.rgb(17, 255, 0));        
    colorBlack.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
    colorWhite.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    colorBlue.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 255));
    colorYellow.setColor(Color.rgb(243, 243, 21));
    colorRed.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    colorCyan.setColor(Color.rgb(51, 255, 255));
    colorMagenta.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 255));
    colorOrange.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 119, 0));
    transparent.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    // Set glow colors
    glowGreen.setColor(Color.argb(150, 17, 255, 0)); 
    glowWhite.setColor(Color.argb(150, 255, 255, 255));
    glowBlue.setColor(Color.argb(150, 0, 0, 255));
    glowYellow.setColor(Color.argb(150, 243, 243, 21));
    glowRed.setColor(Color.argb(150, 255, 0, 0));
    glowCyan.setColor(Color.argb(150, 51, 255, 255));
    glowMagenta.setColor(Color.argb(150, 255, 0, 255));
    glowOrange.setColor(Color.argb(150, 255, 119, 0));
    glowBlack.setColor(Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));

    translucentGrey.setColor(Color.argb(100, 205, 201, 201));

    lobsterFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(Assets, "fonts/Lobster.otf");

    countPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    countPaint.setTextSize(60);
    countPaint.setTextAlign(align.RIGHT);
    countPaint.setTypeface(lobsterFont);

    boostPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    boostPaint.setTextSize(40);
    boostPaint.setTextAlign(align.CENTER);
    boostPaint.setTypeface(lobsterFont);


    ///// End Colors /////

    timer = new Timer();


    random = new Random();
    Playing = false;
    event = random.nextInt(4);
    boost = random.nextInt(4);

    clock();



    box = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.box);

    play = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start);
    title = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);


    ballBlue = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ballblue);
    ballRed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ballred);
    ballYellow = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ballyellow);
    ballGreen = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ballgreen);

    dp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dp);
    wg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.widegaps);
    rocket = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rocket);
    ghost = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ghost);



    // Get window size and save it to screenWidth and screenHeight.
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size); 
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    rowSpace = (int) (100 * density);

    boostdiam = (int) (25 * density);

    int nor = screenHeight / rowSpace; // Number of rows to be displayed.

    /**
     * Generate rows and gaps at set intervals.
     * Chooses a random color for each row.
     */
    for (int row = 0; row < nor + 1; row ++) { 
        final int gap = (int) (random.nextInt(maxGap) + minGap * density);
        final int block = random.nextInt(screenWidth - gap);

        blockY[row] = screenHeight * 1/2 + row * rowSpace; // Positions first block at center screen.
        blockX1[row] = block;
        blockX2[row] = block + gap; 
        blockcolor[row] = random.nextInt(8);

        passedrow[row] = false;

        halfgap = (float) (blockX2[0] + blockX1[0]) / 2; // Used for centering start button to first gap.           

    }


    randomEvent = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(EventTimeMax) + EventTimeMin;
    randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;
    eventRandomX = random.nextInt(screenWidth);

    meteorBounds.set(eventRandomX * density, -50 * density, eventRandomX + 50 * density, 0 * density);
    pointLossBounds.set(eventRandomX * density, -50 * density, eventRandomX + 50 * density, 0 * density);
    pointGainBounds.set(eventRandomX * density, -50 * density, eventRandomX + 50 * density, 0 * density);
    speedBounds.set(eventRandomX * density, -50 * density, eventRandomX + 50 * density, 0 * density);


    System.out.println(density);

    scoreText = score.toString();

}

// Called back to draw the view. Also called by invalidate().
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {




    // Once game is started and paused is set to true, pause all counters.          
    if (Playing == true && rocketboostOn == false) { 
        scrollSpeed = oldSpeed;
        scrollSpeed -= scrollInterval;
        oldSpeed = scrollSpeed;
    }

    int rowBlockHeight = screenHeight / 32;

    playerBounds.set(playerX - playerRadius * density, (float) playerY - playerRadius * density, playerX + playerRadius * density, (float) playerY + playerRadius * density);

    int nor = screenHeight / rowSpace;

    for (int row = 0; row < nor + 1; row ++) {              
        blockY[row] = blockY[row] + scrollSpeed;

        rowBlock.set(0, (float) blockY[row],(float) blockX1[row], (float) blockY[row] + rowBlockHeight);
        rowBlock2.set((float) blockX2[row], (float)blockY[row], (float) screenWidth, (float) blockY[row] + rowBlockHeight);

        rowGlow.set(-20, (float) blockY[row] - 10, (float) blockX1[row] + 10, (float) blockY[row] + rowBlockHeight + 10);
        rowGlow2.set((float) blockX2[row] - 10, (float) blockY[row] - 10, (float) screenWidth + 20, (float) blockY[row] + rowBlockHeight + 10);

        if (blockY[row] < screenHeight) {

            if (blockcolor[row] == 0 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowGreen);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowGreen);                    
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }
            }
            if (blockcolor[row] == 1 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowRed);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowRed); 
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }
            }
            if (blockcolor[row] == 2 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowBlue);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowBlue);
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }          
            }
            if (blockcolor[row] == 3 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowWhite);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowWhite);
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }                   
            }
            if (blockcolor[row] == 4 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowYellow);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowYellow);
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }                    
            }     
            if (blockcolor[row] == 5 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowCyan);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowCyan);
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }                   
            }   
            if (blockcolor[row] == 6 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowMagenta);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowMagenta);
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }               
            }
            if (blockcolor[row] == 7 && gwboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowOrange);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowGlow2, 4 * density, 4 * density, glowOrange);
                if (rocketboostOn == false) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, colorBlack);
                } else {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                }   
            }
            if (gwboostOn == true) {
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
                canvas.drawRoundRect(rowBlock2, 3 * density, 3 * density, translucentGrey);
            }
        }


        if (blockY[row] < 0) {

            final int gap = (int) (random.nextInt(maxGap) + minGap * density);
            final int block = random.nextInt(screenWidth - gap);

            if (row == 0) {
                blockY[row] = blockY[nor] + rowSpace + rowBlockHeight;
            } else {
                blockY[row] = blockY[row - 1] + rowSpace;
            }

            blockX1[row] = block;
            blockX2[row] = block + gap;
            blockcolor[row] = random.nextInt(8);
            passedrow[row] = false;

        }

        if (passedrow[row] == false) {

            if (playerBounds.top > blockY[row]) {
                passedrow[row] = true;
                score += 1;
                scoreText = score.toString();

                if (dpboostOn == true) score += 2;

            }

        }


        if (playerBounds.bottom > rowBlock.top && playerBounds.top < rowBlock.bottom && (playerBounds.left < blockX1[row] || playerBounds.right > blockX2[row]) && rocketboostOn == false && gwboostOn == false) {
                youLose();                  
        }

        if (doublePointsOn == true && dpboostOn == false) {
            doublePointsBounds.set(boostIconX, (float) blockY[boostIconRow] - boostdiam - 20, doublePointsBounds.left + boostdiam, doublePointsBounds.top + boostdiam);

            canvas.drawBitmap(dp, null, doublePointsBounds, null);

            if (hasCollided(doublePointsBounds.left, doublePointsBounds.top, doublePointsBounds.right, doublePointsBounds.bottom)) {    
                boostTime = 10;
                dpboostOn = true;                       
            }

            if (doublePointsBounds.bottom < 0) {
                doublePointsOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;
            }
        }

        if(dpboostOn == true && rocketboostOn == false && wgboostOn == false && gwboostOn == false) {
            scoreInt = 2;

            if(boostTime < 1) {
                dpboostOn = false;
                doublePointsOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;
                scoreInt = 1;

            } else {
                canvas.drawText("Double Points", screenWidth / 2, 25 * density, boostPaint);
                canvas.drawText(boostTime.toString(), screenWidth / 2, 55 * density, countPaint);
            }
        }





        if (rocketOn == true && rocketboostOn == false) {

            bulletBounds.set(boostIconX, (float) blockY[boostIconRow] - boostdiam - 20, bulletBounds.left + boostdiam, bulletBounds.top + boostdiam);
            canvas.drawBitmap(rocket, null, bulletBounds, null);

            if (hasCollided(bulletBounds.left, bulletBounds.top, bulletBounds.right, bulletBounds.bottom)) {    
                boostTime = 5;
                oldSpeed = scrollSpeed;

                rocketboostOn = true;                       
            }

            if (bulletBounds.bottom < 0) {
                rocketOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin; 
            }

        }

        if (rocketboostOn == true && dpboostOn == false && wgboostOn == false && gwboostOn == false) {

            scrollSpeed = oldSpeed * 1.5;


            if(boostTime < 1) {
                rocketboostOn = false;
                rocketOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;
                scrollSpeed = oldSpeed;

            } else {
                canvas.drawText("Rocket", screenWidth / 2, 25 * density, boostPaint);
                canvas.drawText(boostTime.toString(), screenWidth / 2, 55 * density, countPaint);
            }
        }



        if (widegapsOn == true && wgboostOn == false) {

            wideGapsBounds.set(boostIconX, (float) blockY[boostIconRow] - boostdiam - 20, wideGapsBounds.left + boostdiam, wideGapsBounds.top + boostdiam);
            canvas.drawBitmap(wg, null, wideGapsBounds, null);

            if (hasCollided(wideGapsBounds.left, wideGapsBounds.top, wideGapsBounds.right, wideGapsBounds.bottom)) {    
                boostTime = 10;
                wgboostOn = true;                       
            }

            if (wideGapsBounds.top < 0) {
                widegapsOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin; 
            }

        }

        if (wgboostOn == true && rocketboostOn == false && dpboostOn == false && gwboostOn == false) {                      

            minGap = 200;
            maxGap = 250;

            if(boostTime < 1) {
                wgboostOn = false;
                widegapsOn = false;

                minGap = 100;
                maxGap = 150;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;

            } else {
                canvas.drawText("Wide Gaps", screenWidth / 2, 25 * density, boostPaint);
                canvas.drawText(boostTime.toString(), screenWidth / 2, 55 * density, countPaint);
            }
        }


        if (ghostWallOn == true && gwboostOn == false) {

            ghostWallBounds.set(boostIconX, (float) blockY[boostIconRow] - boostdiam - 20, ghostWallBounds.left + boostdiam, ghostWallBounds.top + boostdiam);
            canvas.drawBitmap(ghost, null, ghostWallBounds, null);

            if (hasCollided(ghostWallBounds.left, ghostWallBounds.top, ghostWallBounds.right, ghostWallBounds.bottom)) {    
                gwboostOn = true;
                boostTime = 10;

            }

            if (ghostWallBounds.top < 0) {
                ghostWallOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;
            }


        }

        if(gwboostOn == true && rocketboostOn == false && wgboostOn == false && dpboostOn == false) {



            if(boostTime < 1) {
                gwboostOn = false;
                ghostWallOn = false;
                randomBoost = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(BoostTimeMax) + BoostTimeMin;

            } else {
                canvas.drawText("Ghost Walls", screenWidth / 2, 25 * density, boostPaint);
                canvas.drawText(boostTime.toString(), screenWidth / 2, 55 * density, countPaint);
            }
        }

    } // End of main FOR loop
    //canvas.drawText(scrollSpeed.toString(), 200, 200, scoreColor);

    if (score < 0) {
        youLose();
    }

    int playHeight=87; int playWidth=96;
    playBounds.set(halfgap - playWidth / 2 * density, (float) (blockY[0] - rowSpace), halfgap + playWidth / 2 * density, playBounds.top + playHeight * density);

    playerBounds.set(playerX - playerRadius * density,(float) playerY - playerRadius * density, playerX + playerRadius * density, (float) playerY + playerRadius * density);

    canvas.drawOval(playerBounds, transparent); // Draw player

    if (Playing == true) canvas.drawText(scoreText, 350 * density, 30 * density, countPaint);


    int titleWidth = 256; int titleHeight = 76; 
    titleBounds.set(screenWidth / 2 - titleWidth / 2 * density, 10 * density, titleBounds.left + titleWidth * density, titleBounds.top + titleHeight * density);


    if (Playing == false) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(play, null, playBounds, null);    
        canvas.drawBitmap(title, null, titleBounds, null);
    }   


    //change to 10          // Events // 
    if (score > 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() > randomEvent) {


        if (meteorOn == false && pointLossOn == false && pointGainOn == false && speedEventOn == false) {


            event = random.nextInt(4);              
            eventY = random.nextInt(15) + 5;

            if (event == 0) {
                meteorOn = true;
            } else if (event == 1) {
                pointLossOn = true;
            } else if (event == 2) {
                pointGainOn = true;
            } else if (event == 3) {
                speedEventOn = true;
            }                   

        }



        if (meteorOn == true) {
            MeteorEvent(5, eventY);
            if (meteorBounds.centerX() < screenWidth && meteorBounds.centerY() < screenHeight && meteorBounds.centerX() > 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(ballRed, null, meteorBounds, null);
            }   
        }

        if (pointLossOn == true) {
            PointLossEvent(5, eventY);
            if (pointLossBounds.centerX() < screenWidth && pointLossBounds.centerY() < screenHeight && pointLossBounds.centerX() > 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(ballBlue, null, pointLossBounds, null);
            }
        }
        if (pointGainOn == true) {
            PointGainEvent(5, eventY);
            if (pointGainBounds.centerX() < screenWidth && pointGainBounds.centerY() < screenHeight && pointGainBounds.centerX() > 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(ballGreen, null, pointGainBounds, null);
            }
        }
        if (speedEventOn == true) {
            SpeedEvent(5, eventY);
            if (speedBounds.centerX() < screenWidth && speedBounds.centerY() < screenHeight && speedBounds.centerX() > 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(ballYellow, null, speedBounds, null);
            }
        }



    } // End of events //


    // change to 20
    if (score > 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() > randomBoost) {

        if (doublePointsOn == false && rocketOn == false && widegapsOn == false && ghostWallOn == false) {

            boost = random.nextInt(4); 

            System.out.println(boost);
            //boostIconRow = random.nextInt(nor) + nor / 2;
            boostIconRow = 1;
            boostIconX = random.nextInt((int) (screenWidth - 50 * density)) + 50;

            if (boost == 0) {
                doublePointsOn = true;
            } else if (boost == 1) {
                rocketOn = true;
            } else if (boost == 2) {
                widegapsOn = true;
            } else if (boost == 3) {
                ghostWallOn = true;
            }

            System.out.println(ghostWallOn);
        }

    }

    //canvas.drawBitmap(play, null, playBounds, null);        


    if(score > 50) {
        EventTimeMax = 4000;
        EventTimeMin = 2000;         
    } else if (score > 100) {   
        EventTimeMax = 3000;
        EventTimeMin = 1000;    
    } else if (score > 250) {
        EventTimeMax = 2000; 
        EventTimeMin = 1000;
    }



    // Delay    
    try { Thread.sleep(10); }
    catch (InterruptedException e){}
    invalidate(); // Force a re-draw
}

public void clock() {

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (boostTime > 0) {
                boostTime -= 1;
            } 

        }

    }, 0, 1000);   

}

// Called back when the view is first created or its size changes.
@Override public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {

    // Set the movement bounds for the ball
    xViewMax = w - 1;
    yViewMax = h - 1;

}


public void highscoreSaver() {

    if(finalScore > MainActivity.prefs.getInt("HighScore", 0)) {
        MainActivity.prefsEditor = MainActivity.prefs.edit();
        MainActivity.prefsEditor.putInt("HighScore", score);
        MainActivity.prefsEditor.commit();

    }

}

public void youLose() {

    View LoseScreen = new LoseScreen(getContext());
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
    finalScore = score;

    highscoreSaver();

    timer.cancel();

    parent.addView(LoseScreen);
    parent.removeView(this);
    parent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);

}

public void MeteorEvent(float slopeX, float slopeY) {

    if (eventRandomX < screenWidth / 2) {
    meteorBounds.left += slopeX; meteorBounds.right += slopeX;
    } else {
    meteorBounds.left -= slopeX; meteorBounds.right -= slopeX;
    }
    meteorBounds.top += slopeY; meteorBounds.bottom += slopeY;

    if (!(meteorBounds.centerX() < screenWidth && meteorBounds.centerY() < screenHeight && meteorBounds.centerX() > 0)) {

        randomEvent = System.currentTimeMillis() + random.nextInt(EventTimeMax) + EventTimeMin;
        eventRandomX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - 20) + 20;
        meteorBounds.set(eventRandomX * density, -50 * density, eventRandomX + 50 * density, 0 * density);  
        meteorOn = false;
    }   
    if (hasCollided(meteorBounds.left, meteorBounds.top, meteorBounds.right, meteorBounds.bottom))  
        youLose();
}


public boolean hasCollided (float left, float top, float right, float bottom) {

    if (((playerBounds.bottom > top && playerBounds.bottom < bottom) || (playerBounds.top < bottom && playerBounds.top > top)) 
        && ((playerBounds.left > left && playerBounds.left < right) || (playerBounds.right < right && playerBounds.right > left))) {

        return true;        
    } else {    
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    // Get finger's X and Y position
    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

    if(x > playBounds.left || x < playBounds.right && y < playBounds.bottom && y > playBounds.top) {

        Playing = true;         
    }


    if (Playing == true) {

                switch (e.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    playerX = x;
                    playerY = y;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    youLose();
                }
            }

    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: In general it is helpful to reproduce your problem as the smallest complete example rather than simply dumping your whole program.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing tons of work on main thread hence android is skipping the frames and your app is opening slowly.
Use threading or AsynkTask for background work.
take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: All my work is really done in 1 file, so what do you suggest me to do, I don't really get how this works

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem, I am drawing many bitmaps to the screen, which is pretty heavy work. I am drawing my bitmaps in a method that renders every 10ms. So I'm thinking this is the issue. When I commented out all of my bitmaps(canvas.drawBitmap(...)) the game ran much smoother. There must be a way to load images a different way, to be used for graphics etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your code on another thread ?

like this:

```
              Thread t=new Thread(){

                    @Override
                    public void run(){
                    //paste code here

                    }
                };
```

Comment: So just draw all my bitmaps in new threads? I have come to the conclusion that drawing the bitmaps to canvas is what is lagging it so hard. It is also causing some images to not show when I export it to a phone. Could this be a result of this too?